# How to overcome import error with opencv in ipython

Tags: opencv, jupyter, ipython

I believe I finally installed OpenCV using the following command.

```
conda install -c anaconda opencv
```

it seems I can load opencv in python3

however, when I try to import this in ipython or jupyter, I get the following:

### In [1]: import cv2

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-72fbbcfe2587> in <module>()
----> 1 import cv2
```

> ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mycomputer/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libintl.8.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Users/mycomputer/anaconda/lib/libharfbuzz.0.dylib
>     Reason: image not found

Comment: I have the same issue, and do you find answer?

Comment: Yes ... I ran this code. https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv

Comment: conda install -c conda-forge opencv    
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken opencv

Comment: after run `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`, and run import cv2 still got the same error info like your question says.

Comment: it turns out i did make notes. Have you tried this?

Comment: [link] https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv

Comment: **conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken opencv**

Comment: Yes, I have tried this command: `conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken opencv` but the error still there: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/keen/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libopenblasp-r0.2.19.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/keen/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/libopencv_hdf.3.2.0.dylib
  Reason: image not found```

Answer (score 1):

By run this command:`pip install opencv-python`, I fixed this issue.

Comment: cool! I was going around in circles. )) I think this is how it should work.

Comment: It helped me as well.